# how to take flowfile count in nifi queue?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have nifi flow(standalone) like

```
executestreamprocessor(hive script) -> executestreamprocessor(hadoop script).
```

for each and every incoming flowfile, hive script runs with the command INSERT..INTO..SELECT..FROM and hadoop script deletes the particular files from the storage area.

sometimes, hive script is getting failed when simultaneously hadoop script runs the command.

i will be getting maximum of 4 number of files for each an hour. so i planned to use controlrate processor in between the hive and hadoop processors. i set the condition when count of the queue reaches to 4 flowfile, then hadoop script should be executed. But, controlrate has the property to set only for maximum rate. it does not have minimum rate.

is there any possible solution to achieve? or any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) for this, try this Groovy script:

```
def flowFiles = session.get(4)
if(!flowFiles || flowFiles.size() < 4) {
  session.rollback()
} else {
  session.transfer(flowFiles, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

If you only want to trigger the downstream flow once, then you can create a child flow file from the parents (and report a JOIN provenance event):

```
def flowFiles = session.get(4)
if(!flowFiles || flowFiles.size() < 4) {
  session.rollback()
} else {
  def flowFile = session.create(flowFiles)
  session.provenanceReporter.join(flowFiles, flowFile)
  session.remove(flowFiles)
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

Having said that, if you don't care about the flow file contents (i.e. you are using a flow file as a trigger), you could use [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) with a Minimum and Maximum Number Of Entries = 4.

Comment: i will be getting 4 flowfile in a location. i will take each of these files, routed to hive scripts(executestreamprocessor) and hadoop scripts(executestreamprocessor). basically, i will process each file through hive scripts and hadoop script to delete all the files. But i do not want to delete the files individually. here, i dont think executescript(groovy) and mergecontent will fit into. please enlighten more.

Comment: Does the script already know which files to delete (like all from a folder)? If so the second script should work, put it after the hive scripts and before the Hadoop executestreamcommand, then you'll get 4 Hive commands then one Hadoop delete

Comment: is it possible to check the condition of second script for the other relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean error handling in the script?

Comment: suppose, i have 1.executestreamcommand(runs hive scripts) followed by 2.executestreamcommand(runs hive scripts) followed by 3.executestreamcommand(runs hive scripts) followed by 4.executestreamcommand(runs hadoop command). i want hadoop command to be executed only when the first executestreamcommand queue is empty. in this case, we need to check the queue of the first processor. is it possible?

Comment: @mattyb how to count the number of files dynamically ? in case we might have one or more file.

Comment: @O.Sam How do you know when it's "done"? If there's an upper bound you can always schedule the processor to run at an interval when you think "all the flowfiles" will be there, then call session.get(<upper_bound>). For dynamic numbers of flowfiles I think this is as close as you can get